# Display posts every specific day

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

i want to display posts every specific day like post should desplay in evry friday 
with meta key acf date picker

```
    <?php
      $todayName = date('l');
      $schedules = new WP_Query(array(
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'post_type' => 'serie',
          'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'    => 'AND',
            array(
              'key'   => 'status',
              'value'     => '1',
              'compare'   => '=',
            ),
            array(
              'key'   => 'release_date' ,
              'value'     => date('l'),
              'compare'   => '=',
              'type' => 'DATE',
            ),
          ),

      ));
    ?>
```

Comment: This might help `'compare' => 'LIKE', 'value' => '"'.date('l').'"'`. Could you post is being saved to the db by that acf-field?

Comment: Yes my post saved with acf and I try this and it not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the return-format of the acf-field as 'l'

[image]

& then modify your query as follows:

```
$todayName = date('l');
$schedules = new WP_Query([
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'serie',
  'meta_query' => [
    'relation'    => 'AND',
    [
      'key'   => 'status',
      'value'     => '1',
      'compare'   => '=',
    ],
    [
      'key'   => 'release_date' ,
      'value' => '"'.todayName.'"',
      'compare' => 'LIKE', 
      // You might try this too. If you can use this instead of `LIKE` please do, because it's more efficient
      // 'value' => todayName,
      // 'compare' => '=',      
    ]
  ]
]);
```

Comment: not working  this is making me crazy haha

Comment: @KaisBO Did you re-save the values after changing how they're saved? You'll need to re-save the posts, changing the way acf saves doesn't retroactively update all the previously saved post-meta. This can be done more efficiently by selecting all-items from the all-posts edit page & making a doing a bulk quick-edit; instead of re-saving them one by one. Also, what values do you see being saved in the post-meta? Could you post them here, please? That's 1/2 the problem